# When value is stored in Shared Preferences activity Second Activity Opens with intent value

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

In my app I want to launch activity which store a value and intent to next activity.Then when I open app for next time If value is present in shared preferences first activity will not open. I tried so many logics but nothing work for me.Kindly help me out.

```
package com.jsm.irs;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 // UI References
private EditText textEtxt;
private Button saveButton;
private Button activity2Button;

private String text;

private SharedPreference sharedPreference;

Activity context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    findViewsById();

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text = textEtxt.getText().toString();

            // Hides the soft keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textEtxt.getWindowToken(), 0);

            // Save the text in SharedPreference
            sharedPreference.save(context, text);
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.saved),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    activity2Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            // Start next activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void findViewsById() {
    textEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_text);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    activity2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_second_activity);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

this is Shared-preferences class

```
package com.jsm.irs;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

 public class SharedPreference {

 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "AOP_PREFS";
 public static final String PREFS_KEY = "AOP_PREFS_String";

public SharedPreference() {
    super();
}

 public void save(Context context, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,            Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
    editor = settings.edit(); //2

    editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, text); //3

    editor.commit(); //4
}

public String getValue(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    String text;

    //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    text = settings.getString(PREFS_KEY, null);
    return text;
}

public void clearSharedPreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

public void removeValue(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.remove(PREFS_KEY);
    editor.commit();
}    
}
```

Second Activity class

```
package com.jsm.irs;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import com.jsm.irs.SharedPreference;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;


 public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

// UI References
private TextView textTxt;

private String text;

private SharedPreference sharedPreference;

Activity context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    findViewsById();

    //Retrieve a value from SharedPreference
    text = sharedPreference.getValue(context);
    textTxt.setText(text);

}

private void findViewsById() {
    textTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You have two buttons in the first activity. Apparently the user first has to use the first button to save a value to shared preferences. After that he has to click the second button to start the second activity. You did not tell all those things. I blame you! Now at every start of your app you should check in onCreate of first activity if the value in shared preferences is ok. And if so start second activity.

Comment: EXACTLY I WANT WHAT YOU SAY..KINDLY HELP ME OUT

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    package com.jsm.irs;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     // UI References
    private EditText textEtxt;
    private Button saveButton;
    private Button activity2Button;

    private String text;

    private SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    Activity context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

        findViewsById();
        if(sharedPreference.getValue(this).equals("YOUR_TEXT")){
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
         finish();
         }
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text = textEtxt.getText().toString();

                // Hides the soft keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textEtxt.getWindowToken(), 0);

                // Save the text in SharedPreference
                sharedPreference.save(context, text);
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.saved),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        activity2Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                // Start next activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
private void findViewsById() {
    textEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_text);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    activity2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_second_activity);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: I missed that function in my code. I have edited my answer, please check.

Comment: Text you have saved in your shared preferences when going to second activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you save the value to.Preference did the Toast shows the value saved? Is there any error after saving the value to preference? Because if the value isn't saved properly then null will return when you are getting it.

Solution: 
Read the SharedPreference Value from the MainActivity onCreate Method, if the value is present start Activity2 else start Activity1

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 // UI References
private EditText textEtxt;
private Button saveButton;
private Button activity2Button;

private String text;

private SharedPreference sharedPreference;

// Activity context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
// Read SharedPreference Value 
String prefValue = shared preference.get value(Main activity.this); 
If(prefValue.equals(wantedValue) || prefValue != null)
{
Intent openActivity2 = new Intent(Main activity.this, Second activity.class); 
startActivity(openActivity2); 
}

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text = textEtxt.getText().toString();

            // Hides the soft keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textEtxt.getWindowToken(), 0);

            // Save the text in SharedPreference
            sharedPreference.save(context, text);
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.saved),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    activity2Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            // Start next activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void findViewsById() {
    textEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_text);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    activity2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_second_activity);
}
```

Comment: NO..THERE IS NO ERROR
PLEASE SUGGEST ME IF ELSE LOGIC CODE TO SOLVE MY ISSUE

Comment: Please read my editted answer solution paragraph. Read the Value from MainActivity onCreat() if the value is not null and correct open Activity2 Else Open.Activity 1

Comment: PLEASE SEND ME THE CODE

Comment: OK let me Have look quickly

Comment: Please check my Edited answer

Comment: The Value you are expecting the Preference to return..if the value is unknown then change it to if(prefValue != null)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to marked it as answered.  Have fun Coding

Comment: Why are you asking for that? Two hours before you the right answer was already given twice.